# node.js db-migrate create extension issue

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, npm, dbmigrate

I use the db-migrate to create the table. I have a sql statement. 
`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;`
But I got a error.

> [ERROR] AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: ifError got unwanted exception: could not load library "/Users/manlokwong/PostgreSQL/pg96/lib/postgresql/pgcrypto.so": dlopen(/Users/manlokwong/PostgreSQL/pg96/lib/postgresql/pgcrypto.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/pgbin-build/pgbin/shared/osx_64/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Users/manlokwong/PostgreSQL/pg96/lib/postgresql/pgcrypto.so
>     Reason: image not found
>       at Connection.parseE (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:553:11)
>       at Connection.parseMessage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:378:19)
>       at Socket. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate-pg/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:280:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:638:20)

Answer (score 0):

The extension is unable to load an OpenSSL shared library at /opt/pgbin-build/pgbin/shared/osx_64/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib. Try fully reinstalling your PostgreSQL distribution or using one from Homebrew.